# What company's staff checks boarding passes at the gates at Tbilisi airport?

Tags: airports, paperwork, check-in, qatar-airways, tbilisi

I'm soon flying from Tbilisi (TBS) to London (LHR) via Doha (DOH) on Qatar Airways (because of a fare glitch - it's a **single booking**). As my passport is getting replaced, I will only have access to my ID card, with which I can exit Georgia and enter the UK, but not enter Qatar (which I don't intend to either)

Since [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=SE&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=00&TR=QA&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C) says nothing about whether I need a passport simply to change planes at DOH, I called the Qatar Airways UK hotline, who told me I was fine to travel. I also gave the IATA travel centre a shot - it said I was good to go.

Unfortunately, Qatar Airways refused to send me a confirmation via e-mail, instead saying I should print the Timatic extract to show staff at TBS if necessary.

The problem is that [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=SE&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=00&TR=QA&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C) says nothing about this specific issue, and in my own experience, most gate staff are reluctant to let you fly somewhere **even for transit** without a document accepted for **entering** that country.

So, what I need to know is **who checks boarding passes at the gate at TBS**, because I need to contact them to clear this up **immediately**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51203/discussion-on-question-by-crazydre-what-companys-staff-checks-boarding-passes-a).

Comment: Did you end up finding out?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently TAV Georgia is the sole ground handling agent at Tbilisi airport.

Regarding the actual issue: I called Qatar Airways's central hotline and explained my situation, whereby they put a note in the system "IN TRANSIT TO LONDON HOLDING A NATIONAL ID CARD. OK TO BOARD".

Despite having checked in online and printed my boarding pass, I went to the check-in desk 4 hours before departure to get a written confirmation to show gate staff, as I wasn't sure they'd have access to the system like the check-in staff.

After 30 minutes of bickering with a lady about whether I could travel, and insisting that she summon her supervisor, she eventually did. He checked the system for 3 minutes, eventually asking me "you go to London?" I said yes, whereby he said "wait" and called someone. Then, he printed out two fresh boarding passes and put a special stamp on the Tbilisi-Doha one (presumably similar to Ryanair's and Wizz's stamps indicating a non-EU passenger has been cleared), and told me I could go to the gate.

When I presented the documents at the gate, the agent scrutinised the stamped boarding pass for 20 seconds, before saying "OK, have a good flight".

That was the end of it - the rest of the trip was 100% painless.